# What is the $RR$ notation in this calculation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, notation

[image: Circuit problem]

This is a circuit problem I am working on, and I was trying to figure out the impedance (both as a complex and real solution) of the circuit as a whole. I was looking at this tutorial and I am not sure what the RR notation is in the calculation. Does anyone know what it is, and how they could write up a solution using standard mathematical notation?

Comment: RR must be his short-hand way of showing two impedances in parallel.

Comment: It is customary to accept a correct answer, like the one @Jan gives below.  Click the check mark to accept.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we know that series resistor can be added (with the '+'-operator). So we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

And it is not that hard to see that:

$$\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}=\text{R}_1+\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_x}{\text{R}_2+\text{R}_x}$$

Where:

$$\text{R}_x=\text{R}_3+\frac{\text{R}_4\text{R}_5}{\text{R}_4+\text{R}_5}$$